# Linear Algebra - Vector spaces and generators. Needs explaining.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

"Let V be a vector space und $ v_1, ..., v_m $ $\in$ V.

If ($ v_1, ..., v_m $) is a generator, then the dim(span(($ v_1, ..., v_m $)) $\ge$ dim(V)."

Nothing about linear (in)dependence is said.
I thought it was the other way round (the relation) and thought about how the generator doesn't have to be a basis, but I'm struggling with the dimensions, or rather this specific relation.

Comment: Is span subspace of $V$?

Comment: " For M being a subset of V, a vector space, we get the span of K over M and say span(M), which is the smallest subspace of V that contains M.
If M has only one element, the span equals a line through (0,0). If M has two different elements, the span is the plane." (translation of my script)

Comment: I thought generally, the span of elements of a vector space is a subspace.

Comment: Generally span is space, but is it subspace of $V$?

Comment: I would have thought so, because the elements form a subset of V. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now, can be subspace dimension more or less, then space dimension?

Answer (score 0):

To say that a subset $A$ of a vector space $V$ is a generator of $V$ is the same thing as saying that its span is $V$. That is, $\mathrm{span}(A) = V$, implying $\dim \mathrm{span}(A) = \dim V$.

Comment: Th thing throwing me off is the "equal/greater than".
But apparently, in the dimension of the span are all the vectors. In the vector space you throw out the linear independent from the span and you're left with a basis, which has fewer vectors. (that's what a fellow student said).

Comment: I wonder if you've got the question right. Once you know $\mathrm{span} (A) = V$, it's obvious they have the same dimension as they are the same thing. Perhaps the task was to show that $m \geq \dim V$? That would follow, but strict equality wouldn't, as knowing that a set is spanning only implies that it contains a basis, which may be smaller than the spanning set.